# .NET HttpClient - Measuring stream download speeds

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

How can I measure the download rate when copying from a stream?
Here's my download code:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
using (var respStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(Url))
{
    using (var file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        await CopyToAsync(respStream, file);
        file.Flush();
    }
}
```

PS: I'm using a custom `CopyToAsync` implementation, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://wantbo.wordpress.com/2020/01/17/how-to-download-a-file-in-c-progressbar-and-download-speed/ ?

Comment: This article too : https://www.geekinsta.com/how-to-measure-internet-speed-using-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it. The answer was to create a cache where I add the `bytesRead` value I got out of the `sourceStream.ReadAsync(...)` in my custom `Stream::CopyToAsync(...)` implementation. Then do the standard speed calculation:

(I used a stopwatch to measure the time it took to download)

```
bytesPerSecond = bytesRead / watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

If you'd like to see the implementation of `Stream::CopyToAsync(...)`, you can find that here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,08ee62b6d544c8fe